# .gitignore not working after adding it to already modified repo.

Tags: git, version-control, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.gitignore file not ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

I checked out a big repo and worked on it for a day which created lot of temp files. When I cloned the repo, I forgot to add .gitignore to it. So, now I see lot of temp files. I added my .gitignore to the root directory. Also copied the same rules to /.git/info/exclude. Still I 
see the same set of files. Am I doing some stupid mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you untrack those temp files after adding the .gitignore?

from [github](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files),

> Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a
>   rule was added to this file to ignore it. In such a case the file must
>   be un-tracked, usually with git rm --cached filename

Answer (score 3):

To first remove the cached contents

```
git rm -r --cached
```

then add and push

```
git add .

git push
```